# Select parent and all its siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I want to select an elements parent and it's siblings. However, choosing the `.parent().siblings()` does not include the original elment's parent.

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
```

How can I select the parent's siblings and the parent itself too?

Comment: You want to remove class from both parent and it's siblings?

Answer (score 7):

Use jQuery's `addBack()` method:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().addBack().removeClass("active");
```

This selects an element's siblings, and itself, so that you can remove the class.

*If you're using a jQuery version less than 1.8, use `andSelf()` instead.*

**Update**: I've added an example below to show exactly what this method will do.

```js
$('.active a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().addBack().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {background: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="active">I'm active. <a href="#">Remove all active</a></div>
<div class="active">I'm active. <a href="#">Remove all active</a></div>
<div class="active">I'm active. <a href="#">Remove all active</a></div>
<div class="active">I'm active. <a href="#">Remove all active</a></div>
<div class="active">I'm active. <a href="#">Remove all active</a></div>
```

Comment: `andSelf` is deprecated.

Comment: Doesn't this select the parent's siblings and the original element? What I want is to select the parent's siblings and the original element's PARENT.

Comment: It selected the original item's parent, and its siblings. I've added an example to my answer.